# Azure Mobile App losing TimeZone of DateTimeOffset

Tags: json.net, azure-mobile-services

When I send a `DateTimeOffset` value to an Azure Mobile App inside an object property it changes it to UTC, but I want to keep the `TimeZone`.

Both client and server `JsonSerializerSettings` are set to `RoundtripKind` by default but seems that this is not working.

How can I keep the `TimeZone`when working with `DateTimeOffset` properties?

Answer (score 0):

When you send DateTimeOffset, you can pass the time zone information in TimeSpan.

You may go through this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime) for more information.

Also, you may try converting back to Time Zone from UTC again.

For reference here is the [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can go through.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, it's a possible solution, but this is not what I want. because it implies to write especific code both on client and server. I want to change the way that Azure Mobile App is handling DateTimeOffset values to mantain the timezone which is missing due to Json serialization and deserialization. As a temporary workarround I'm serializing and deserializing this values manually and doing this the timezone is correctly saved.